# python and sys.argv

Tags: python

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: sys.argv[0] ')
    sys.exit(1)


if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Database sys.argv[1] was not found!')
    sys.exit(1)
```

This is a portion of code I'm working on. The first part I'm trying to say if the user doesn't type `python programname something` then it will exit.

The second part I'm trying to see if the database exists. On both places I'm unsure if I have the correct way to write out the sys.argv's by stderr or not.

Comment: In your first if-block doing print `'Usage:' + sys.argv[0]` does not tell the user that they need to type "python [program\_name] [something]". It only prints "Usage: [program\_name]". You might want to come up with a better error message.

Comment: This should be called "python and sys.stderr", tho it actually helped me on the `argv` :P

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me, @Cawas

Comment: What is the **question** here?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

BTW you can pass the error message directly to sys.exit:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit('Usage: %s database-name' % sys.argv[0])

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    sys.exit('ERROR: Database %s was not found!' % sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 34):

In Python, you can't just embed arbitrary Python expressions into literal strings and have it substitute the value of the string. You need to either:

```
sys.stderr.write("Usage: " + sys.argv[0])
```

or

```
sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s" % sys.argv[0])
```

Also, you may want to consider using the following syntax of `print` (for Python earlier than 3.x):

```
print >>sys.stderr, "Usage:", sys.argv[0]
```

Using `print` arguably makes the code easier to read. Python automatically adds a space between arguments to the `print` statement, so there will be one space after the colon in the above example.

In Python 3.x, you would use the `print` function:

```
print("Usage:", sys.argv[0], file=sys.stderr)
```

Finally, in Python 2.6 and later you can use `.format`:

```
print >>sys.stderr, "Usage: {0}".format(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Note that 'Usage: {0}'.format(sys.argv[0]) is now the recommended way of formatting strings.

Comment: Also note that sys.stderr.write() will not add a trailing newline, so you should include one explicitly.

Answer (score 32):

I would do it this way:

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s <database>" % (argv[0],))
        return 1

    if not os.path.exists(argv[1]):
        sys.stderr.write("ERROR: Database %r was not found!" % (argv[1],))
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

This allows `main()` to be imported into other modules if desired, and simplifies debugging because you can choose what `argv` should be.

Comment: This is a nice explanation - I was looking for more information on using  sys.exit( main(sys.argv) ) and why it was encouraged. Thanks for the explanation.