# Python: some newbie questions on sys.stderr and using function as argument

Tags: python, function-pointers, stderr

I'm just starting on Python and maybe I'm worrying too much too soon, but anyways...

```
log = "/tmp/trefnoc.log"

def logThis (text, display=""):
    msg = str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) + " TREfNOC: " + text
    if display != None:
        print msg + display
    logfile = open(log, "a")
    logfile.write(msg + "\n")
    logfile.close()
    return msg

def logThisAndExit (text, display=""):
    msg = logThis(text, display=None)
    sys.exit(msg + display)
```

**That is working**, but I don't like how it looks. Is there a better way to write this (maybe with just 1 function) and is there [any other thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983201/python-and-sys-argv) *I should be concerned under exiting*?

---

Now to some background (but not about [trefnoc](http://code.google.com/p/trefnoc/))...

Sometimes I will call `logThis` just to log and display. Other times I want to call it and exit. Initially I was doing this:

```
logThis ("ERROR. EXITING")
sys.exit()
```

Then I figured that wouldn't properly set the `stderr`, thus the current code shown on the top.

My first idea was actually passing "sys.exit" as an argument, and defining just `logThis ("ERROR. EXITING", call=sys.exit)` defined as following (showing just the relevant differenced part):

```
def logThis (text, display="", call=print):
    msg = str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) + " TREfNOC: " + text
    call msg + display
```

But that obviously didn't work. I think Python doesn't store functions inside variables. I couldn't (*quickly*) find anywhere if Python can have *variables taking functions* or not! Maybe using an `eval` function? I really always try to avoid them, tho. Sure I thought of using `if` instead of another `def`, but that wouldn't be any better or worst.

Anyway, any thoughts?

Comment: Tho I accepted an answer, I'm still missing some information for the **stderr** part. But unless someone says something, I'm just assuming there's nothing more that could be done on that side.

Comment: `sys.stdout` is where `print` generally outputs, `sys.stderr` is where exceptions output, but you can use `print` with it by going `print >> sys.stderr, 'blah'` if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason for "logThisAndExit", it doesn't save you much typing over

```
sys.exit(logThis(text)+display)
```

(compare `logThisAndExit(text, display)`)

or

```
sys.exit(logThis(text))
```

(compare `logThisAndExit(text)`)

Not that I'm entirely sure why you like your exit messages formatted as log lines.

In answer to your original question: you're missing parentheses: `call(msg+display)` works fine. But I think that's waaaay overengineering for logging/exiting stuff. Anyone who maintains your code will have to understand your function to know when it's exiting and when it's not.

Comment: Well, it's just for the looks. It hits much better on the eye to write `logThisAndExit("ERROR, EXITING.")` than `  sys.exit(logThis("ERROR, EXITING", display=None) + "ERROR, EXITING")`. But this helped me a lot of thinking and I'm also not entirely sure if I want my exit messages formatted as log. Thanks! :D

Comment: Oh, and reason why call wasn't working is pointed in the other answer - `call=print` in the argument couldn't be done. If that was right, then I'd have an issue with `call msg+display` as well, as you pointed out, tho.

Comment: @Cawas - speaking as a long-term Python developer, I tend to agree with moshez that `logThisAndExit` is unidiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

For logging, it is probably easier to use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.

For exiting, if you have any error, use:

```
sys.exit(1)
```

and if there is no error, either just let the script run out of statements or:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: well, what about putting the error message under `sys.exit`, like I did? is that a 1 or 0?

Comment: The quickest way to find out is to test it. Just run your app from the command line and then see what the return code was (` echo $?` on unix/linux or `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `logThis` to take a final argument called `shouldExit` which defaults to `None`, then as a final step in that method, if the value is true then call `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a keyword, not a function, in python < 3. try this:

```
def do_print(x):
    print x

def logThis (text, display="", call=do_print):
    msg = str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) + " TREfNOC: " + text
    call(msg + display)
```

Is there any reason you don't use the `logging` module? (see http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/06/02/logging.html)

Comment: I'm on python 2.6.4 and that worked quite well, thanks! No reason for not using the module. I was just introduced for it and will take a look, so, thanks again! ;)

Comment: Pending output is supposed to flush automatically whenever files are gracefully closed, which includes non-anomalous exits (excluding some corner cases involving threads which aren't shut down gracefully). Can you demonstrate the necessity of that `time.sleep(1)` with a modern interpreter?

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in *my* code :-) I was using a logger which ran in a separate thread so it didn't lock up the interpreter and trims the length of lines as Eclipse raises an exceptions if the lines are longer than a certain point, that must have been it

Answer (score 0):

Just as reference, this is my final code after assimilating hints from David and moshez. In the end I decided I wanted just 1 function for now. Thanks everyone!

```
log = "/tmp/trefnoc.log"

def logThis (text, display=""):
    msg = str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) + " TREfNOC: " + text
    if display != None:
        print msg + display
    logfile = open(log, "a")
    logfile.write(msg + "\n")
    logfile.close()
    return msg

# how to call it on exit:
sys.exit(logThis("ERROR, EXITING", display=None))
```