# Graphene Python mutation list input

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphql-python

I have a mutation that looks like this

```
class ApisInteractiveGlobal(BaseMutation):
success = Boolean()
error = String()

class Arguments:
    user_id = List(ID)
    api_name = String()
    global_apis = Boolean()
    my_org_api = Boolean()

def mutate(self, info, user_id=[], api_name=None, global_apis=None, my_org_api=None):
    for id in user_id:
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        api = user.apis_interactive.get(name=api_name)
        if my_org_api is not None:
            api.my_orgapis = my_org_api
        if global_apis is not None:
            api.global_apis = global_apis
        api.save(update_fields=['global_apis', 'my_orgapis'])
    return ApisInteractiveGlobal(success=True)
```

Here, I'm trying to pass a list of users at a time to update some values in my code. But the mutation is throwing errors. Can someone suggest a list input for the mutation as an example?

Comment: Hi, can you please add the errors the mutation is throwing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing any of list of values of other types is easy using similar to list(String)
For example

```
class ApisInteractiveGlobal(BaseMutation):
success = Boolean()
error = String()

class Arguments:
    user_id = List(ID)
    apis = List(String)
    global_apis = Boolean()
    my_org_api = Boolean()

def mutate(self, info, user_id=[], apis=[], global_apis=None, my_org_api=None):
    for id in user_id:
        for api in apis:
            user = User.objects.get(id=id)
            api = user.apis_interactive.get(name=api)
            if my_org_api is not None:
                api.my_orgapis = my_org_api
            if global_apis is not None:
                api.global_apis = global_apis
            api.save(update_fields=['global_apis', 'my_orgapis'])
    return ApisInteractiveGlobal(success=True)
```

In the above code, to pass a list of user ids and list of strings I've used list(ID) & list(String). It worked

Comment: Be careful not to use mutable default arguments like `user_id=[], apis=[]`. Python will actually instantiate a single list that will be mutated across all usage of the function. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9158294/1570062