# Owerwriting of class results in old data in python

Tags: python, class

Recently run into following problem using python 2.7:
I have class like this:

```
class Comment():
    def __init__(self, preComments = [], postComment = ''):
        self.__preComments = preComments
        self.__postComment = postComment
```

I use code like this multiple times:

```
# self.commentQueue holds comment.Comment()
def getQueuedComment(self):
    queuedComment = self.commentQueue
    self.commentQueue = comment.Comment()
    return queuedComment
```

Idea of this code is to return instance of Comment and create new instance in place, so queuing may continue.

And result is that weirdly, but each time second code is called `self.commentQueue` holds data from all other instances of this class(data are appended not assigned and problem occurs only with list), but as I understand that `self.commentQueue = comment.Comment()` should create new, empty class, by empty I mean that `self.__preComments = []` and `self.__postComment = ''`.

Fix is to call `self.commentQueue = comment.Comment([], '')` instead of `self.commentQueue = comment.Comment()`, but I just don't understand why this happens.

Comment: That is a Python gotcha, see [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639915/why-the-mutable-default-argument-fix-syntax-is-so-ugly-asks-python-newbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `[]` as a default argument value. This expression is only evaluated once, so *all* calls to your function will always use the same `list` instance. Make it like this instead:

```
class Comment():
    def __init__(self, preComments = None, postComment = None):
        if preComments is not None:
            self.__preComments = preComments
        else:
            self.__preComments = []
        if postComments is not None:
            self.__postComment = postComment
        else:
            self.__postComment = []
```

Comment: `self.__preComments = preComments or []` or something more explicit `self.__preComments = [] if preComments is None else preComments`

Comment: Using an `or` isn't foolproof, as you cannot pass in a Falsy value.

Comment: @Darthfett Yes, that's why I wrote the second example as well. But if we expect it to be a `list` then it's ok to use or. Luckily, list in python with whatever in it is considered "True".

Comment: @rpInt Explicit is better than implicit.  Just thought I would leave a comment for those who might not know.  (Note the fact that I didn't address you in my comment. :) )

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you use mutable variable type as constructor parameter (`preComments = []`). See this: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)