# Python Class and Instance Variables

Tags: python, class, instance-variables, mutable, class-variables

In working through the [python tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), it describes class and instance variables.  My question is this:  **In the example below, why does 'kind' behave like an instance variable even though it is declared (at least by its position as a class variable?**

I followed the tutorial example and defined the dog class as

```
class Dog:
    kind = 'canine'         # class variable shared by all instances
    tricks = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name    # instance variable unique to each instance
```

I then created two instances and printed out the variables

```
d = Dog('Fido')
e = Dog('Buddy')
print('After initialize instances:     {!s:<8}{!s:<10}{!s:<}'.format(d.name, d.kind, d.tricks))
print('After initialize instances:     {!s:<8}{!s:<10}{!s:<}\n'.format(e.name, e.kind, e.tricks))
```

and recieved the expected output.

```
After initialize instances:     Fido    canine    []
After initialize instances:     Buddy   canine    []
```

I then append to fido tricks with

```
d.tricks.append('roll over')
```

and got the expected output from similar print statements:

```
After append roll over to Fido: Fido    canine    ['roll over']
After append roll over to Fido: Buddy   canine    ['roll over']
```

I understand why Buddy also has 'roll over.'  The tricks are a class variable.  What I don't understand is I then set fido.kind to cat with

```
d.kind = 'cat'
```

Which only changes the value for the instance 'd.'  Simular print statements give:

```
After set Fido kind to cat:     Fido    cat       ['roll over']
After set Fido kind to cat:     Buddy   canine    ['roll over']
```

**Why is the type of the instance 'e' or Buddy still canine?**

Finally, I set the tricks to a list rather than appending, and it only changed the result returned by 'd' or 'Fido.'  In other words after:

```
d.tricks = ['play dead', 'roll over']
```

Similar print statements give:

```
After set Fido tricks to list:  Fido    cat       ['play dead', 'roll over']
After set Fido tricks to list:  Buddy   canine    ['roll over']
```

I know similar questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833320/python-class-and-instance-attribute-confusion), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424451/compound-assignment-to-python-class-and-instance-variables) (to name a few).  But I still don't get it.  I think my misunderstanding has something to do with [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-mutable) objects and when the [idenity](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#id) is set.  If someone could help me that would be great.

Also, I wonder **'Is 'kind' really a class variable?'**
Also,
**Can I / Should I define instance variables not in the class methods but just under the class definition as 'kind' is in this example?**

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: Assigning to `d.kind` doesn't assign to the class variable. It assigns to an instance variable. The fact that there is also a `kind` class variable doesn't matter.

Comment: as @user2357112 points out `d.kind = ...` creates an instance variable called kind. What you really need to do is change `Dog.kind = ...`. When you reference `d.kind` (outside of assignment) then it checks the local scope of `d` doesn't find it so checks for `Dog.kind` and finds it.

Comment: Thanks!  So, in python, you can add a new variable to an instance after the instance is created.  I didn't know that.  A 'print(Dog.kind)' does always give 'canine.'