# Default parameter value for objects

Tags: python, default-value

Python provides a way to set a default value for function parameters. An example is:

```
def f(x=3):
    print(x)
```

This is for a primitive type, lets try with objects:

```
def f(x=list()):
    print(id(x))     
f()
```

> 44289920

```
f()
```

> 44289920

Same object! I was surprised of this being used to the C/C++ way. Done with that, I now understand the default value is not build at invoking time but at definition time.

So I came to a solution:

```
def f(x=list()):
    if len(x) == 0:
        x = list()
    print(id(x))
```

Solved! But at what price: In my opinion this doesn't seem to be a very clean solution.
This solution rely in the use of `len(x) == 0` as a way to identify the default value which is Ok for my function but not for others so the solution can be generalized as:

```
def f(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = list()
```

This can be shortened to:

```
def f(x=None):
    x = x or list()  # a bit shorter version
```

My question is, is there any shorter or better way to solve this problem? Will it ever be?

Comment: `x=list()` is executed exactly once when the `def` is executed. So the default value for `x` of *all*  calls to `f` refer to the same object.

Comment: @LutzHorn Read on; that isn't the question.

Comment: The question is: "is there any shorter or better way to solve this problem? Will it ever be?". The answer is: No, because (see above).

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here. That *is* the way to solve the problem.

Comment: @LutzHorn More above "Done with that, I now understand the default value is not build at invoking time but at definition time." The answer can be "No, there isn't"

Comment: @DanielRoseman The question is: I do not like this solution particularly and I would like to know if there is another mechanism.

Comment: Related: [Why the “mutable default argument fix” syntax is so ugly, asks python newbie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639915/why-the-mutable-default-argument-fix-syntax-is-so-ugly-asks-python-newbie)

Comment: Only improvement you can do here is to use `x is None` instead of `==`.

Comment: Just quick note: `if x == None:` should be `if x is None:`. see [PEP8 recommendations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id41)

Comment: @Shadow9043 Thank you! Just edited the question to follow this recommendation.

Comment: @200OK Thank you! Just edited the question to follow this recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still prefer the is None approach, but here is a new option to think about: If is defined only the type, you create a new instance of it.

```
def f(x=list):
    if isinstance(x, type): x = x()
    print(id(x))
```