# IndexError: list index out of range Python Argument Input

Tags: python

```
import sys
#print sys.argv[1]
def IndexSearchString():


    This function search a string in a file through index and gives the result.



    #fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1
    stringsrch = sys.argv[2]
    #size = len(sys.argv)
    file_name = open("passwd", "r")
    #print "No of Argu ", size
    ''' 
    if sys.argv[1] == Null:
        print "Please enter argument"   
    '''
    if sys.argv[1].isdigit():
        fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1
    else:
        print "Enter integer in 1st Argument"
        sys.exit(1)
    fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1

    stringsrch = sys.argv[2]

    if len(sys.argv) > 3 :
        print "Enter two arguments only"
        sys.exit(1)

    for store_file in file_name:
        temp = store_file.split(":")
        search = temp[fieldindex]
        #print search 

        if stringsrch in search:
            print store_file

IndexSearchString()
    '''
    My Question is:
    I am taking two argument in the command line. Now I want to handle when only one     argument is given and also when no argument is given.
    Help me out 

    Error:
    Command Window Input: python SearchString.py 1 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "SearchString.py", line 46, in <module>
    IndexSearchString() 
    File "SearchString.py", line 36, in IndexSearchString
    stringsrch = sys.argv[2]
    IndexError: list index out of range
    '''
```

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: Python has clearly modules like "argparse" for doing commandline options handling _properly_ - at least much better than your code.

Comment: when i take no argument i want that to be handled without try except

Comment: Search string is missing

Comment: i am not giving search string, and its is giving me error and i want that to be handled

Comment: i am an newbie in python

Comment: Just use [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/)

Comment: How are you calling this program. Ie what are typing on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this question out and see if it can help
[python and sys.argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983201/python-and-sys-argv)
add this after your "def..."

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3 :
  print "Please enter two arguments"
  sys.exit(1)
```

and change your other one

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3 :
        print "Enter two arguments only"
        sys.exit(1)
```

to

```
if len(sys.argv) > 4 :
        print "Enter only two arguments after the program"
        sys.exit(1)
```

even easier

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 0 | len(sys.argv) < 3 :
  fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1  
else:
  sys.exit("enter up to 2 args")
```

Comment: adding this after def still shows the same error

Comment: by the way you dont need to define searchsrch twice

Answer (score 0):

this

stringsrch = sys.argv[2]

should probably be this

stringsrch = sys.argv[1]

because no other place do you use

sys.argv[2]

Comment: but already i am using sys.argv[1] for indexing

Comment: because of line 6 and 20 you would have to give the program two  arguments you only gave it one

Comment: `if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
    print "Enter two arguments"
    sys.exit(1)` you should also add this before you do anything in your script

Answer (score 0):

in your Opinion: you should start with 0 in sys.argv

Comment: where should i change that in my code ?

Comment: it would be great if u help me out

Comment: if you think you need second parameter, you uses `sys.argv[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-invent the wheel, but use one of the existing python command line argument parsers:

- [docopt](http://docopt.org/) - (from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt), `pip install docopt`)
- [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) - (it is in standard library)