# How to ask user's input to make a code interactive

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created this code:

```
gene = open("AY365046.1.txt","r")

g=0;
a=0;
c=0;
t=0;

gene.readline()

for line in gene:
    line = line.lower()
    for char in line:
        if char == "g":
            g+=1
        if char == "a":
            a+=1
        if char == "c":
            c+=1
        if char == "t":
            t+=1

print "Guanina: " + str(g)
print "Adenina: " + str(a)
print "Citosina: " + str(c)
print "Timina: " + str(t)

gc = (g+c+0.) / (a+t+c+g+0.)

print "Conteúdo GC: " +str(gc)
```

Now I want to make it interactive... My objective is use the **input()** funcion to get the "sequence number" which will display the corresponding data...

On the code above, it obtains only the data of one sequence/file (AY365046.1.txt)... Therefore, I need the code to get access to more files (for exemple, **sequence1.txt** and **sequence2.txt**)... And then, get the data of **g**, **a**, **c** and **t** on the sequence/file informed on the **input()** function...

For exemple:

1) The system ask for the Sequence Number

2) The user type **sequence2**

3) The system get data from **sequence2.txt**

4) The variables **g**, **a**, **c** and **t** get the data from that file

5) If the sequence doesn't exist, print an error...

As far as I understand, to do all that, I just need to declare the variables, assign the .txt files to each one of them, and make an if/else...

The problem is that I have tried all that I could find, and nothing works...

Obviously I am not asking to make the code for me, but... Can you guys at least tell me where do I need to start? My logic for what I need to do is correct? I am missing something?

Comment: I see that you are not closing your file. you should use gene.close() in some part of your code. or use with open("AY365046.1.txt","r") as f: ..

Comment: Instead of `input`, you can enter the filename in the command line with `sys.argv`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983201/python-and-sys-argv). Also, you don't need `gene.readline()`.

Comment: What behaviour do you observe and what behaviour did you expect? You seem to skip the first line in the file (due to the `gene.readline()` expression).

Comment: Exactly that, @skyking ... I get the file from the NCBI database, and the first line is useless... The real data is below that, so...

Comment: I'm going to try, rsm and tmoreau... Thanks..

Comment: @Ricardo, you should explain what you are expecting about your program. And also don't forget to accept the answer so it be removed from the unanswered questions

Comment: You can use `guanina = line.count('g')`  `cytosina = line.count('c')`and after that divide `len(line)/(guanina+cytosina)`. I know you're just a beginner but less is more!

Comment: @vds Thanks... I will :)

Comment: `(guanina+cytosina)/len(line)` is the right way, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
import os

id = raw_input('please enter the file numbers id:')
file='AY{0}1.txt'.format(id)

if not os.path.exists(file):
    print "Error the file doesn't exists"
else:
    g,a,c,t=0,0,0,0
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            for char in line.lower():
                if char == 'g':
                    g+=1
                if char == 'a':
                    a+=1
                if char == 'c':
                    c+=1
                if char == 't':
                    t+=1

    print "Guanina: {0}".format(g)
    print "Adenina: {0}".format(a)
    print "Citosina: {0}".format(c)
    print "Timina: {0}".format(t)

    gc = (g+c+0.) / (a+t+c+g+0.)

    print "Conteúdo GC: {0}".format(gc)
```

But I think that you should explain the expected behavior of your code because it is not really clear.

Comment: He's trying to calculate the %GC in a DNA-string. So basically calculating tha % of total letters G or C make up of a string consisting of A,C,G & T

Comment: It works, thanks! But how can I skip the first line of the file now? I was using gene.readline() for that...

Comment: @Ricardo I've added the line skip, it is by using `next(f)`. Also keep in mind that everything you asked has been already responded! Search engines are your best friend :), good luck!

Comment: @vds is right... I need to skip the first line of the file because of that... The file comes from NCBI database, and the first line is a brief definition of the gene... And I don't want to get the G's, A's, C's and T's on this, only on the rest of the file...

Comment: Thanks again, @rsm! :)

Comment: @rsm But now, with the `next(f)`, I am getting this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gc.py", line 15, in <module>
    for line in f.readlines():
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`

Comment: @Ricardo Sorry I made the correction.( I didn't added the vds answer about using `count`, but you should! )

Answer (score -1):

The problem I see in your code is that you only read one line from the text file. The code below will return a list of the entire document so you could iterate upon that the way the rest of your code does.

```
with open("AY365046.1.txt","r") as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
```

You can read more about the file object in the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)

Comment: No, the iteration over the file (`gene`) actually reads the rest of the lines. Perhaps the first `readline` is just to skip the first line?

Comment: I'm not really sure about his "readline()" but he's mostly asking about using `raw_input` to get the file names